# Docker tini no such file or direcory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tini

so i have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /vault

COPY run.sh /vault/run.sh
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /vault/docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY config/local.json /vault/config/local.json
COPY logs /vault/logs
COPY file /vault/file

ENV TINI_VERSION v0.19.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini
RUN chmod +x /vault/run.sh
RUN chmod 777 /vault/docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl gnupg2 && \
  curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | apt-key add - && \
  apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  vault bash && \
  setcap cap_ipc_lock= /usr/bin/vault

ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--" , "/vault/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
#CMD ["sh", "/vault/run.sh"]
```

And the file structure is:

```
-docker-vault (dir)
|-Dockerfile (file)
|-docker-entrypoint.sh (file)
|-run.sh
|- file (dir)
|- logs (dir)
|- config (dir)
   |- local.json
```

And i get the following error when running the dockerfile:

```
[FATAL tini (8)] exec  /vault/docker-entrypoint.sh failed: No such file or directory
```

I already tried to check the file structure with dive and everything was fine. every file was copied where it belongs to.. so i thought this may be an error with the ENTRYPOINT command and tini, since CMD finds the file and runs it

Here is the dive: [image: Dive Results]

Comment: What is the very first line of `docker-entrypoint.sh`?  (Could you use the [Docker Hub `vault` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/vault) instead of rolling your own?)

Comment: @DavidMaze It's: #!/bin/zsh , already tried to use the vault image, still not working.... I was wondering why to use zsh but its the only substitution supported(installed). I tried #!/usr/bin/dumb-init /bin/sh but this seems only to work with alpine. And when starting it it gives me following error:  /bin/sh: apt-get: not found

Comment: If you can rewrite the script to use only [POSIX shell syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18) and change the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh` it should work on any base image.  If your script _really_ requires zsh, it's probably not going to be installed by default.

Comment: @DavidMaze i was able to get it running with bash by ust editing my entrypoint to following:
    
`    ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "bash", "/vault/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: @DavidMaze Now i get a new error: `/vault/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 104: exec: su-exec: not found` line 104 is: `exec "$@"`

Comment: I think you will have to install `su-exec` in ubuntu

Comment: Already tried that, it gives me the following error: Unable to locate package su-exec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated your `COPY` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands.

Try the following Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /vault

COPY ./run.sh ./run.sh
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh ./docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY ./config/local.json ./config/local.json
COPY ./logs ./logs
COPY ./file ./file

ENV TINI_VERSION v0.19.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini
RUN chmod +x run.sh
RUN chmod 777 docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl gnupg2 && \
  curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | apt-key add - && \
  apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  vault bash && \
  setcap cap_ipc_lock= /usr/bin/vault

ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "bash", "/vault/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Okay I updated your `ENTRYPOINT`, try now

Comment: Sorry, I updated multiple times. Could you double-check you have my latest update? If you have the latest, what is the error you see?

Comment: Ok, Double checked it and it's still not working.... hmmm.....

Comment: [FATAL tini (7)] exec docker-entrypoint.sh failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Updated the Question and added the results of dive

Comment: Okay, I updated the ENTRYPOINT again with a new CMD at the end. That is according to `tiny` documentation

Comment: With cmd it should be working but it gives me the error bad substitution...

Comment: So it doesn't work with ENTRYPOINT and CMD as well?

Comment: If you want to combine, try `ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "sh", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: i now found out i have to use bash not sh. now i get following error: /vault/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 104: exec: su-exec: not found... line 104 is: exec "$@"

Comment: Add this to your answer so i can mark it as correct, and i'll see if i can fix the other error :) thank you very much !             `COPY ./run.sh ./run.sh
    COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh ./docker-entrypoint.sh
    COPY ./config/local.json ./config/local.json
    COPY ./logs ./logs
    COPY ./file ./file
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "bash", "/vault/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Great, I updated the answer. Happy to be of help! 